# Android-Delete LiveData returned from Room Database

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have below my code which returns Live Data from the Room Database.

```
@Dao
public interface CustomersDao {

@Transaction @Query("SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY Customers.Name ASC LIMIT :index,:fetchPace")
LiveData<List<Customers>> fetchNextCustomers(int index, int fetchPace);

}
```

And in my repo i have this:

```
 public LiveData<List<Customers>> fetch(int index,int fetchPace){
    return mDatabase.repoCustomers().fetchNextCustomers(index,fetchPace);
}
```

**My questions**:

1. Each call to fetch method, returns a new live data object?
2. Does each of the newly created live data objects stored somewhere by the
   Framework itself? (we dont store them explicit by ourselves) Because, how the system will know when a change made in
   Room which live data objects to notify?.
3. If 2 is true, how can we delete those live data objects to free memory?

Comment: yes, its kept when using `observe()` method and automagically released when `LifecycleOwner` says "ok im no longer active" (or you call `removeObserver*()` method)

Comment: and for ad 1) yes its always a new live data object